# create a dictionary of key value pairs in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class item {
    int size;
    int value[30];
    char key[30][20];
    int n, k;
    int index;
    char* a[30], *b[30], search, remove;

public:


    void putdatavalue(void) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cout << value[i] << ","
                 << "\n";
        }
    }

    void display(void) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cout << "(" << key[i] << "," << value[i] << ")"
                 << "\n";
        }
    }


};

void item::getdata(void) {
    cout << "entr size\n";
    cin >> size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "entr key\n";
        cin >> key[i];
        cout << "entr value\n";
        cin >> value[i];
    }
    cout << "chk whether keys are different \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        a[i] = key[i];
        b[i] = key[i + 1];
        if (*a[i] == *b[i]) {
            cout << "key" << i << "and key" << i + 1 << "are same\n";
            cout << "re-entr key\n";
            cin >> key[i + 1];
        } else {
            cout << "key[" << i << "] and key[" << i + 1 << "] are diff\n";
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    item obj1;
    obj1.getdata();
    int m;
    do {
        cout << "choose ur option and enter appropriate no"
             << "\n";

        cout << "\n1 : display keys \n";
        cout << "\n2 : display value \n";
        cout << "\n3 : display key-value pair \n";
        cout << "\n4 : add a key-value pair \n";
        cout << "\n5 : remove a key-value pair \n";
        cout << "\n6 : search for key and its value \n";
        cout << "\n7 : quit \n";
        cin >> m;

        switch (m) {

            break;

            case 1: {
                obj1.putdatakey();
            } break;
            case 2: {
                obj1.putdatavalue();
            } break;
            case 3: {
                obj1.display();
            } break;

            case 7:
                break;

            default:
                cout << "error in input \n";
        }
    } while (m != 7);
    return 0;
}
```

I am suppose to create a dictionary of `key-value` pairs in C++ with the following functions:
**display keys, display values, display key-value pairs, add a key-value, delete a key-value pair, find out if a key is present and return it value**.

It should be possible for dictionary to be empty.

You should overload the `operator+` to do the *union* of two dictionaries and if the dictionaries each contain the same key, output an error message.

My teacher asked us not to use `strings` and `vectors` so i used arrays
I am stuck with the union function and don't know how to do it. Plz help me out.

Comment: If you're allowed to, use `std::map`...tada!

Comment: _"my teacher asked us not to use strings and vectors"_ - You should ask for a refund.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious it might be simply to get them to think about what's going on under the hood and implement such tools themselves for learnings sake. Although I admit it does seem strange in this example.

Comment: @OMGtechy Exactly my point. The task is to create a dictionary of key value pairs. Asking them to not use `std::string` and `std::vector` adds unnecessary complexity that is of little value at their current stage of learning and puts the student in very undesirable situation.

Comment: There are so many problems here, where to start... 1) the constructor does not initialize size, n, k, or index. Using them without initializing is undefined behavior. 2) "key[30][20] = '\0';", as used in the constructor, is undefined behavior. 3) "value[30]=0;", as used in the constructor, is undefined behavior. ... This is a mess. Did you cut class, at the beginning of the course? Looks like you're missing some fairly basic fundamentals, here.

Comment: @abc this is really a few questions rolled into one. If you know how to do it with an `std::vector` then you're really asking how to make an `std::vector` as well, for example. Just break the problem into smaller and smaller parts until the solution shines through.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik is right, A good question may yet emerge about how to do the data structure but the code in general needs major work.

Comment: @abc Editing your question to delete all of the code after the question has been answered is rude to others and against the purpose of this site.  If you have a new question, you should post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

> my teacher asked us not to use strings and vectors so i used arrays

If there is no restriction, then I would use `std::map`.

With restriction, I would use **Binary Search Tree** with the following key structure

```
struct BstNode {
    int       key_;      // 'int' or some other appropriate
    int       value_;    // - do - 
    BstNode * left_;
    BstNode * right_;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As was previously stated, a map would be the best avenue given that your teacher is asking for key-value pairs.  Since the specifications state that you're basically not allowed to use any built-in libraries, a simple Google search for `how maps are implemented in c++` returned a link to a pdf ["Implementing Maps"](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/courses/cs106b/chapters/12-implementing-maps.pdf).

Since a map contains unique key values, it is defined as a [Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) mathematically.  Looking at how a union works in a set should help.

When it comes to overloading `operator+`, another Google search yielded ["9.2 — Overloading the arithmetic operators"](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/92-overloading-the-arithmetic-operators/).

Welcome to the science part of Computer Science!

Answer (score 0):

As @Arun said, use a Binary Search Tree for the dictionary.

The result of a union is everything from both dictionaries.

The easiest method is to *traverse* the other dictionary, node by node, inserting the other dictionary's  pairs into *this* dictionary.  Update your *insert* method to not allow duplicates.